# Logical error in finding 100 factorial

Tags: c++, computer-science

I am trying to compute factorial of any integer up to 100 but some random output is coming .
Compiler-Codeblocks
https://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2/

```
 int main()
    {
    int t,i,n,x,j=1,temp=0;
    cin>>t;     //Number of test cases
    int m=1;
    int a[200];//Array to store maximum digit number

    a[0]=1;  
    while(t>0)
       {
       cin>>n;
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         {
         for(j=0;j<m;j++)
           {
           x=a[j]*i+temp;
           a[j]=x%10;
           temp=x/10;
           while(temp!=0)
             {
              a[m]=temp%10;
              temp=temp/10;
              m++;
             }
          }
      }
      for(j=m-1;j>=0;j--)
      {
          cout<<a[j];
      }
      cout<<"\n";
      t--;
   }
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: what you mean, "digit up to 100"? 100 is three digits.

Comment: means to calculate factorial of integer 100

Comment: Provide an example of an input, and the expected output vs actual output.

Comment: t=1,n=5 output=5050000,expected output =120

Comment: It would be good manners to at least explain the logic you are going with in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code. It's ugly. Please use more whitespace and commenting. It takes a while to figure out what certain variables represent.

With that in mind I think you need to separate your `for` and `while` loops that are inside your `for(j = 0; j < m; j++)` loop. The `while` loop should not be in the `for` loop:

```
for(j = 0;j < m; j++)
{
    x= a[j] * (i+temp);
    a[j] = x%10;
    temp = x/10;
}

while(temp != 0)
{
    a[m] = temp%10;
    temp /= 10;
    m++;
}
```

^ Do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop is executing one more time when the while loop modifies the value of `m`. You need to break out of the loop then.

Here's a solution,

```
bool done = false;
...

   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
     done = false;
     for(j=0;j<m;j++)
     {
       x=a[j]*i+temp;
       a[j]=x%10;
       temp=x/10;
       while(temp!=0)
         {
          a[m]=temp%10;
          temp=temp/10;
          m++;
          done = true;
         }
         if (done) break;
      }
   }
```